# SonarQube Project Administration General Settings error on Visual Studio configuration

Tags: c#, sonarqube

We just upgraded our SonarQube server to version 6.2. On the page Administration of our .Net Project, on the Tab "General Settings" we have an error:

'sonar.dotnet.visualstudio.solution.file' and 'sonar.visualstudio.solution' cannot be used at the same time as they refer to the same setting

Further the Configurations that we hat on the previous version of SQ are gone.

Has anyone had the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

You're using some outdated plugins, please update your plugins to latest compatible version and remove the plugins that are no more compatible.
(You probably need to use the SonarC# plugin => https://docs.sonarqube.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=1441900)